# UWP Equivalent to ManipulationDelta Cancel

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

In WPF4, it is possible to cancel a manipulation event and forward it back to mouse events by calling [ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationdeltaeventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'd like to be able to do the same thing in UWP / Windows10, but there is no such cancel method on [ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationdeltaroutedeventargs).

The MSDN documentation refers to [cancellation of a manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/touch-interactions) ...

> Manipulation gesture events, such as ManipulationStarted, indicate an ongoing interaction. They start firing when the user touches an element and continue until the user lifts their finger(s), or the manipulation **is canceled**.

... but doesn't tell you how you can actually do it :?

Comment: Have you tired to call *Complete()* - the [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted(v=vs.110).aspx): `Cancel the manipulation by calling the Complete method.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel it on the `UIElement` you've targeted.

```
element.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;

...

private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;

    element.CancelDirectManipulations();
}
```